Solutions to the negative Pell equation $x^2 - 2y^2 = -2(d^2-2n)$ where $(d,n)$ are positive integers.
I've considered the rather trivial cases wherein $(d^2-2n)$ is prime and from results by quadratic congruences I was able to deduce that the equation has solutions for $p = 8k \pm 1$ since the $(2 \mid p) =1$ for such primes. Moreover, I have found the other solvable cases wherein $2(d^2-2n)$ is a perfect square and $(d^2-2n)$ is a perfect square. Are there any general condition(s) upon $(d,n) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ so that this negative Pell equation is solvable?

"The negative Pell equation" always refers to $x^2-Dy^2=-1,$ not some other negative number after the equal sign.

It's pretty easy to reduce it to $y^2-2z^2=d^2-2n.$ There is a solution to this iff $d^2-2n$ is a product of squares and primes $p=2$ and $p\equiv \pm1\pmod 8.$

You probably won't be able to do much better than factoring $d^2-2n.$

If $n=m^2$ is a square, then $-2(d^2-2m^2)=(2m)^2-2d^2.$ But that won't get even close to all values.

@ThomasAndrews Please elaborate on the iff statement.

The "iff" argument uses that the ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt2]$ is a principal ideal domain, and that the norm of $x+y\sqrt2$ is $x^2-2y^2.$

I'm not yet familiar with principal ideal domains but thanks for the information.

I've provided an alternative proof using Bhaskara's identity and quadratic congruences.
